# Is $\Bbb A^n(k)$ irreducible if $k$ is finite?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Is $\Bbb A^n(k)$ irreducible if $k$ is finite?

For finite field $\exists f(x)$ s.t $V(f)=\Bbb A^n(k)$ but this does not imply anything..

I think if I can show that corresponding any $a \in k$ there a $f \in k[x_1]$ so that $\{a\}=V(f)$ then I am done. So I am trying to find it out.

Yeah I think It's done (Check). Indeed for $a=(a_1,...,a_n) \in k$ $\exists I=(x_1-a_1,....,x_n-a_n)$ s.t $V(I)=a$ if $k$ is finite so is $\Bbb A^n(k) \equiv k^n$ now this is also finite. So take finite union of all this $V(S)$.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by $\mathbb A^n(k)$?

Comment: I have explained.. Sir.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, $\Bbb A^n(A)$ is still irreducible if $A$ is integral. This is a particular case of [10.25.1.](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00ER).

In otherwords: We know that $(0)$ is a minimal prime and $V((0))=Spec (A[x_1,\ldots, x_n])$.